# Detect application update for SPA

Tags: angular, single-page-application, angular-cli

When bundling with `angular-cli`, the chunks get unique names in production mode. Repeating the bundling (e.g. deploying a new version) wipes out the `dist` directory and puts new bundles with new file names there, only the `index.html` is replaced, pointing to the now current bundle names.

This causes problems with already loaded instances of the application when such an outdated version tries to lazy load a bundle and gets a 404.

What is the best practise to address this issue? I can think of several solutions but would like to seek some input.

- Tweak the build process to not remove the outdated files but keep them for some time in parallel. Question then remains: for how long? There is no direct limit for how long an SPA browser window may remain opened.
- Handle the 404 on bundle load somehow and reload the application. Where would that be done best?
- Have a periodic "update" check in the SPA, either with a server side component. This has the benefit of being able to force users to update their SPA when a new version is available but the drawback of requiring server side logic and thereby mixing frontend and backend.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a free reverse proxy such as Cloudflare, it will cache static resources for some time. Actually, wouldn't this be a concern of your build process?

Let's say you build locally and rsync to your server, you'd just replace the replaced files and the old hashes would still exist.

Comment: what if we use docker images, so old files simply do not exist?